# CCSprite in NSDictionary doesn't react to the BoundingBox

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an `NSDictionary` (allSprites) with a lot of Sprites (spriteX) and in my Touch Method I want to check whether the sprite was touched.

My problem is that it doesn't react to the boundingBox. I don't see my error! Is it a problem with `NSDictionary`? I get no error or anything... But it doesn't work.

Is there another way to check the boundingBox in an `NSDictionary`? Can somebody help me?

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  for (UITouch *touch in [event allTouches]) {
    for (NSValue* value in allSprites) {
      CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
      location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
      if(CGRectContainsPoint([spriteX boundingBox], location)){
         NSLog(@"sprite was touched");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you dont seem to refer to spriteX at all in your loop other than in the test for bounding box, it is probably not initialized. maybe you meant to do :

```
for (CCSprite* spriteX in [allSprites allValues]) {
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
  location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
  if(CGRectContainsPoint([spriteX boundingBox], location)){
     NSLog(@"sprite was touched");
  }
}
```

if you need the key of the sprite :

```
for (NSString*key in [allSprites allKeys]) {
  spriteX = [allSprites objectForKey:key];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
  location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
  if(CGRectContainsPoint([spriteX boundingBox], location)){
     NSLog(@"sprite with key %@ was touched",key);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd move `location = ...` lines out of loop.